# How much is Guyver Manga Video Collection worth?

Tags: merchandise, guyver

I'm trying to locate this series on the internet to put a price tag on them. I am pretty sure I have the full series of *The Guyver* animated manga episodes on VHS.

I'm not expecting to be sitting on a gold mine but I was wondering if this series is rare to find on VHS in mint condition especially the full series together. Here is a couple of pictures of the series. If anyone knows more about this series I would love to know because I hope to sell them on.

To point the question to a definitive answer, I'm really wanting to know the value of these videos.

[image: Vertical view]

[image: Horizontal view]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [monetary appreciation questions are off-topic](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4120/2516). The price can fluctuate based on its demand & supply and also time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an [eBay auction](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/The-Guyver-Bio-Booster-Armour-VHS-Tapes-Set-/390823327797?pt=UK_DVD_Film_TV_Videos&hash=item5afee2b835) that is selling the entire series on VHS with the items listed as "Good" condition. Description:

> Good: An item that has been used but is good condition. May have minor damage to jewel case or item cover, including scuffs, cracks, or scratches. The cover art and liner notes are included for a CD. VHS or DVD box is included. Video game instructions are included. No skipping on the CD or DVD, when played. No fuzzy or snowy frames on VHS tape, when played.

It's currently listed with a starting bid of £27.00.

Here's [another eBay auction](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/The-guyver-complete-set-anime-manga-cartoon-Japan-comic-vhs-/271461952600?pt=UK_DVD_Film_TV_Videos&hash=item3f3464ac58) selling the entire set that's listed as "Like New", with this description:

> Like New: An item that looks like it has just been taken out of its shrink wrap. No visible wear, and the item is flawless and intact.

It's currently listed with a starting bid of £25.00

There's a couple of other sellers selling an incomplete set for around $31 or £18.44 so it seems the going price is around the $40 to $45 USD range. Single VHS episodes seem to be asking for more than the entire collection (per VHS tape).

Comment: Although on that auction i can see that none of them have the full collection (all 12)

Comment: @NathanTaylor hmm, based on the picture in the second auction, it looks like they have all 12 (just not in order).

Comment: Ah right you are... thats not very much for a very collectable item I guess I'll be best off finding someone whos really interested in them